# How can I read logcat for only last line?

Tags: android, shell, stdout, logcat

I have seen someone complain about that Logcat only output the last line. I would like to ask a reserve question that how can I produce this condition which only output the last line?

This is how I read the log by start a thread.

```
public class ReadLog implements Runnable{
        private boolean running = true;

        public void stop(){
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Process proc = null;
            try {
                //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat -c");
                proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat ");
              }catch(IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(proc != null){
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String line= null;
                try {
                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null && running){
                        if(line.contains("specific word")){
                            doSomething();//do something base on log
                            running = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    proc.destroy();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to read the newest line only. The problem is that it would trigger the doSomething() even though the "specific word" is not on last line unless I add `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat -c");` the line to clear the log before start running.

It is true that I can add one more `while((line=reader.readLine())!=null && running){}` to let the BufferedReader go to last line before start running but it may take long time and too late.

I have tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat | tail -n 1");`
But no luck that `tail` does not accept stdin.
I am asking for any command that output last line of stdout quickly just like `tail -n 1 FILE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/logcat -d | tail -n 1");`

According to logcat documentation -> -d : "Dumps the log to the screen and exits."

Then readline will return the last new line. (I did not test it).

**EDIT :**

In fact `| tail -n 1` has no effect with "exec", but with "-d" you can get the last log line easily.

```
try {
    //Executes the command.
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "/system/bin/logcat -d");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process
        .getInputStream()));

    String output;
    String lastLine = null;
    while ((output = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lastLine = output;
    }
    reader.close();

    //Waits for the command to finish.
    process.waitFor();

    if(lastLine != null)
        System.out.println("Last log line : " + lastLine);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

**Don't forget to add READ_LOGS permission to your manifest** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Comment: I tried. There is no different without -d. The only different is the process would exit or not.

Comment: My first solution is not working, but i made a new solution which works for me on android 2.3.3, i hope this can solve your problem, sorry I had not seen that you already test this, I can't help you, it's the only way that i found